# Relativity of width between different resolutions using BootStrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to get my head around managing/scoping sizes of html elements in a Body between different resolutions ie Mobile, Pad and Desktop etc.

So, a simple login page will render in a mobile like this:

[image]

Depressingly in my desktop it will look like this:

[image]

I am using this markup:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 " style="margin: 15px; ">
    <div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 7px;">Sign In</div>
        <input type="text" style=" margin-bottom: 7px;" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="email">
        <input type="password" style=" margin-bottom: 14px;" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="">
        <div class=" col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom: 7px;">
            <a style="" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Login</a>
            <a style="" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>
        </div>
        <div style="color: red; color: yellow;" class="text-center">message here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12  text-center">
            <a class="nav-link" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;" ref="#">Reset Pin</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now I can correct/control the width of the inputs by using :

```
max-width: 400px;
```

But is this the 'correct'/'best-practice' way to do things?

When I look at other web sites and see how they render things between different resolutions like, Sky News, the layout is completely different.  I am guessing they either have different versions of their websites or clever use of Divs.

Is the choice up to me or is they a preferred way of doing thing?

I just want to learn...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap try using bootstrap utilities and bootstrap layout in correct way and avoid inline CSS. Check out this code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mt-5">  

      <form>
        <h5>Sign In</h5>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button> 
        </div> 
      </form>

      <div class="text-center">
          <p>message here</p>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><u>Reset Pin</u></a>
      </div>      

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see the key here is the col declarations. I will out when back home to try out and respond. That all of this